# same values should not be selected in two dropdown list of the same table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a table, i have dropdown list in two columns. 
I am working on a client side validation where i should **show a pop message** 
if user selects the same value from the dropdown list's present in the columns 'select Product1' and 'Select Product2' in the same row.

Demo link : http://plnkr.co/edit/oxo8UvtNwyjGSR8y05U3?p=preview

In the demo link, When user selected the laptop and laptop for 'Select Product1' and 'Select Product2' columns of PID 100,
it is showing the pop up with message as expected, but next time when user selected some other value in other row still
it is showing the pop up.

**Note:** My requirement is **for each row**(PID) , if user selects the same product in Select Product1 and Select Product2 columns
a pop up dialog box should be shown with the message "Product name in two drop down list cannot be same.."

```js
//populate dropdown with the value
  function populateSelect(ids) {
     var ids = [{"pid":"laptop","des":"laptop"},{"pid":"Mobile","des":"Mobile"},{"pid":"IPAD mini.","des":"IPAD mini."}]
      var productDropdown1 = $(".product1");
      var productDropdown2 = $(".product2");
      $.each(ids, function(index,value) {
      $("<option />").text(value.des).val(value.pid).appendTo(productDropdown1);
        $("<option />").text(value.des).val(value.pid).appendTo(productDropdown2);
      });
    
    //onchange of the dropdown list 
     $("select").change(function()
     { 
       //var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
       //var valueSelected = this.value;
        var selectedText = $(this).val();
        console.log("selectedText " + selectedText);
        var product1_drop = $('.product1').val(); // Get selected value of product1 dropdown
        var product2_drop = $('.product2').val(); // Get selected value of product2 dropdown
        console.log("product1_drop " + product1_drop);
        console.log("product2_drop " + product2_drop);
           if(product1_drop == product2_drop ){       
                  alert('Product name cannot be same..');
                 }
      });
}
 
$(document).ready(function(){
    populateSelect(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="productTable" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>PID</th>
        <th>Select Product1</th>
        <th>Select Product2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>
            <select class="product1" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="product2" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>
            <select class="product1" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="product2" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>300</td>
        <td>
            <select class="product1" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="product2" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>
            <select class="product1" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="product2" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried trimming and lowering case?

Comment: i'm providing the same list to display in the two columns dropdown lists. So it not the issue with case i believe..

Comment: The issue is that there are multiple product1 and product2 elements, and `val()` does not return an array, nor does it filter down and find the first element with a value.  It will only return the value of the first element in the result stack

Comment: Given the existance of multiple product1 and product2 element, you need to provide more detail in to what exact cases should match your conditional.  Such as if the same value is chosen on differnet rows, if that should be considered a match, or if it is only valid for dropdowns in the same row.

Comment: @Taplar - For each row, select Product1 and Select Product2 should not show/select the same value in the drop down list. If same values are selected in two dropdown list of same row, a pop up message should be shown saying "Values should not be same in Select Product1 and Select Product2"

Comment: Ok, so then `$(this).closest('tr')` would get you the row that the dropdown that was changed belong to.  Then off that guy you just need to find the product1 and product2 that belong to it for your comparison

Comment: Need more detail!

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected when used the below code:

```
 var row = $(this).closest("tr");
 var product1_drop = $('.product1',row).val(); // Get selected value of product1 dropdown
 var product2_drop = $('.product2',row).val();
```